# SQL statement A > B and B > C and A > C

Tags: sql

what is your opinion about?

Let’s say we have WHERE conditions in SQL query like:

```
            Select * from XX where (A > B) and (B > C) and (A > C)
```

how can be rewritten in easier/logical way?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Are all A,B and C integers ?

Comment: [Don't Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask): "I’m curious if other people feel like I do"

Comment: I'm not at all sure what you're even trying to say, if there is a question here, since clearly the two queries presented are not "100% the same"

Answer (score 2):

The third condition is redundant, because if A > B and B > C, then A > C. Hence, your query can be shortened to

```
select * from XX where A > B and B > C
```

If, however, you only keep one condition as you suggested in your original request, you lose a restriction:

- With `where (B < A)`, C could be greater than A or B which is forbidden in the original clause.
- With `where (C < B)`, A could be less than B and C, which is also forbidden in the original clause.

Even if you only keep one of the first conditions plus the last one, you also lose a restriction. With `where (A > B) and (A > C)` you lack the condition that B must be greater than C. With `where (B > C) and (A > C)` you lack the condition that A must be greater than B.

Conclusion: Only the third condition is redundant and can be removed, because it can be deducted from the other two conditions.